# DownloadManager.Request.setNotificationVisibility fails with SecurityException: invalid value for visibility: 2

Tags: android, download-manager

I'm trying to use `DownloadManager` in a `Service` class of mine:

```
    DownloadManager downloadManager = (DownloadManager) getSystemService(DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
    //imageUri is a valid Uri
    Request downloadRequest= new Request(imageUri); 
    //without this line, it works
    downloadRequest.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_HIDDEN);
    //subpath is valid
    downloadRequest.setDestinationInExternalFilesDir(this, null, subPath);
    downloadManager.enqueue(downloadRequest);
```

Without `setNotificationVisibility`, this code works well. But it displays a notification, that I don't want, because I use this code for lazy-loading images in a `ListView`.

I understand, this notification can be hidden with

```
downloadRequest.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_HIDDEN);
```

But in that case, my application crashes with:

> 02-19 02:24:24.055: E/AndroidRuntime(2572):
>   java.lang.SecurityException: Invalid value for visibility: 2 02-19
>   02:24:24.055: E/AndroidRuntime(2572):     at
>   android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1327) 02-19 02:24:24.055:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(2572):   at
>   android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:181)
>   02-19 02:24:24.055: E/AndroidRuntime(2572):   at
>   android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:135)
>   02-19 02:24:24.055: E/AndroidRuntime(2572):   at
>   android.content.ContentProviderProxy.insert(ContentProviderNative.java:415)
>   02-19 02:24:24.055: E/AndroidRuntime(2572):   at
>   android.content.ContentResolver.insert(ContentResolver.java:730) 02-19
>   02:24:24.055: E/AndroidRuntime(2572):     at
>   android.app.DownloadManager.enqueue(DownloadManager.java:885) 02-19
>   02:24:24.055: E/AndroidRuntime(2572):     at
>   MyService.getImage(MyService.java:112)

Whats' wrong with `setNotificationVisibility`? How can I had the notification?

Comment: downloadRequest.setNotificationVisibility(...) helped me...thanks

Comment: before using this method :downloadRequest.setNotificationVisibility(...) please bear in mind that it is Added in API level 11

Answer (score 162, accepted):

You need the following permission in the manifest as per documentation:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.DOWNLOAD_WITHOUT_NOTIFICATION" />
```

**Note**
Most of the manifest permissions will be autocompleted by Android Studio, but this will not be auto-completed.

Comment: as indicated in the documentation... Thanks!

Comment: downloadRequest.setVisibleInDownloadsUi(....)
another useful API to hide it from Download UI.

Comment: I don't see this permission

Comment: This issue still appears to be happening on 5.1.1 (Nexus 5) and the M preview.

Answer (score 1):

but also need to add that permission to rn-fetch-blob's manifest that is not given in it.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.DOWNLOAD_WITHOUT_NOTIFICATION" />
```