# DownloadManager.Request.setNotificationVisibility not working properly when downloading file to external directory

Tags: android, notifications, android-download-manager

```
DownloadManager.Request downloadRequest = new DownloadManager.Request(Uri.parse(f_url[0]));
                downloadRequest.setTitle(Application.getApplication().getString(R.string.app_name));
                downloadRequest.setDescription("Saving..");
                downloadRequest.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(path,filename);
                downloadRequest.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);
                DownloadManager manager = (DownloadManager) Application.getApplication().getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
                manager.enqueue(downloadRequest);
```

If i set download to external directory above code does not shows the notification when file download is completed(It is showing while in progress) .

When i commented the below code line, its working properly

```
//downloadRequest.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(path,filename);
```

Why this is happening and is there any way to resolve.

Comment: whether you got solution?

Answer (score 0):

you should add `DOWNLOAD_WITHOUT_NOTIFICATION` permission in andoroidManifest.xml , please see this :

https://stackoverflow.com/a/33753065/3471640