# Downloaded files not appearing in the Downloads App in android

Tags: android, download, android-download-manager

I am building an application in android where users can download remote files and save them to the external storage downloads directory. It works well and I am able to view files through Es File Explorer and other file explorer tools. But those files are not appearing in **Downloads App** in my Nexus 4 device. Please note that I am not using DownloadManager, instead I am creating HttpUrlConnection to remote server and downloading files.

Can anybody please tell me how to make the downloaded files appear in Downloads App without using DownloadManager?

Answer (score 13):

You have to use `DownloadManager` to make the files show up in the app, but that doesn't mean you have to download them with `DownloadManager`. From API 12 onwards you can call [`DownloadManager.addCompletedDownload`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DownloadManager.html#addCompletedDownload%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20boolean,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20long,%20boolean%29) to add a file you've already downloaded to the downloads `ContentProvider` and therefore also to the GUI.

Comment: This works perfect as well after creating a file in the DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS folder and even gives you a confirmation notification for free. In case you don't want the notification (false as last param of addCompletedDownload) a permission is needed, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/9374821/414581

Comment: @Dan Hulme, can you please provide some source code how we can use this addCompletedDownload method, because it does not seem to work with me.

Comment: This. This answer is awesome.

Answer (score 0):

March 8th, 2017: A bit late to the party but this issue is still present. Check out the issue [here](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=195362).

I also found the solution from [this comment](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=195362#c30). Call this when you finish downloading:

```
MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(
        this,
        new String[]{ file.getAbsolutePath() }, // "file" was created with "new File(...)"
        null,
        null);
```

One side note: One could argue that we'd better use `DownloadManger`. Yes but it is not always available.

Answer (score -3):

Maybe you should use the Downlaod App.

Don't know if this will help:
https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/950273

Comment: Probably not going to help the OP, as he is trying to build his own app to do the downloads. He is trying to figure out why another app on his device does not recognize the downloaded files. Also, try to refrain from off-site links as much as possible, as they can become invalid at some point.